# OpenVPN/Iptables: Route wlan0 through tun0, but not traffic from local system

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I've got a device running OpenVPN with `eth0` (connected to internet), `tun0` connected to VPN, and `wlan0` running hostapd with clients.

I want all the traffic from the clients to go through the VPN, but none of the traffic from the local system to. I have tried copying routes to `table 3` with `ip route` and marking in iptables, and many other iterations, but the only way I can seem to get this working is a `0.0.0.0` route in the main table, which forces all the traffic on the local system to go through the VPN, too.

So, what I'm running right now is basic:

```
    sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
    sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

If I use

```
sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server/server.ovpn --daemon
```

Then of course, everything works, except traffic on the local system is also going through the VPN.

If I use

```
sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server/server.ovpn --daemon --pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway --route-nopull --route-noexec
```

Then the local system continues to go through eth0, but the masquerade traffic from wlan0 is blocked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you give your current settings when the VPN is used? with: `ip -br link; ip -4 -br address; ip route; ip rule; iptables-save -c` ? The solution should require policy routing (eg with this additional table 3) but shouldn't need a mark at all for this simple case (simple because it's at ip level, doesn't involve higher level protocols nor load balancing so shouldn't need iptables)